# Saving/Loading data from JSON to Phonegap/Kendo-UI App

Tags: json, cordova, kendo-ui

First of all I'm very confused with this "JSON" thing, I can't completely get all the concepts but what I actually want to do is some kind of recipes Mobile Phonegap/kendo-UI(or whatever framework) App which should load data from JSON object. But I don't have a website where I could store data. So, what would be options to save and load data from JSON to my app? I mean it's very confusing to ask this, because I actually can't get the JSON, so I'am ready to get a lot of Dislikes but I want to know how to do a thing like that. I don;t know what URL to write and other stuff.

Hope someone will get what I acutally want and if this idea for loading data from JSON is not what I need, hope someone would like to offer other possibilities. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can technically save JSON files locally to your app, then retrieve that data locally. At the end of the day, it's not much different than getting it from a web service (other than the fact that it's going to be static data).

Not to get into too much detail here ([This site has plenty of info](http://www.json.org/)), but JSON is a lightweight flavor of XML for passing data back and forth, very suitable for web services. All it is is key-value pairs. So, in your case, it'll be something like:

```
{ ["RecipeID" : 1, 
  "RecipeName" : "PB&J",
  "RecipeIngredients" : ["Peanut butter", "Jelly", "Bread" ],
  "RecipeDirections" : "If you really have to look this up on an app..."],

  ["RecipeID" : 2,
  // ... 
  ]
}
```

As you can see, it reads pretty clean and is easy to parse. So, in PhoneGap, you'd probably use jQuery and do something like,

```
   $.getJSON("URLorLocationOfJSONfile", null, function(recipes) {
       $.each(recipes, function(i,r) {
            alert("Today, I'd like to eat... " + r.RecipeName);
       )};
    )};
```

And thus iterate through the JSON contents. Put them in a list or something. Whatever you'd like at that point. I build all my PhoneGap apps with JSON on the backend, so you're going in the right direction with that.

You can host the JSON file somewhere out there if you don't want to build an API for it, too. Just replace it when you get new recipes.

Hope that's a start.

Comment: So, technically I can save .json file under my local computer and upload to my project and when I can parse data from it to the PhoneGap app? Thank you very much, napo, you helped me a lot :)

Comment: You sure can. I often use small JSON documents embedded into my app for static configuration settings and such. Think of it as XML, only cleaner. :) It's key-value pairs at the end of the day, so it doesn't matter where you get them from (as long as your browser doesn't throw a fit with cross-domain requests, but that's a topic for another day... ;) ). And thanks for marking it as answered!